# How to determine the location of a number in a column and row

Tags: python-3.x

How to find the location of a number in a list when the numbers that was entered by the user is in columns and rows.

This was the output:

```
1 6 5 8 

9 8 9 7

1 2 4 3
```

So if I want to find the location of 1. it will be row = 1, column = 1

Note: That I am only looking for the first occurrence of the number so when I enter 1 it will only locate the first occurrence.

so this was my code:

```
For i in range(3):

   temp = " "

for j in range(4):

         index = i * 4 +j

   temp +=str(apk[index]) + " "

print(temp)


locRow = apk.index(i)

locCol = apk.index(j)

print('row= ', locRow)

print('column = ',locCol)
```

When I ran the codes it shows no error but the location is not accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Should the result not rather be `(0, 0)` (Python indexing)?

```
l =[[1, 6, 5, 8], [9, 8, 9, 7], [1, 2, 4, 3]]
filterval = 1
for row in range(len(l)):
    try:
        res = (row + 1, l[row].index(filterval) + 1) # added 1!
        break
    except:
        pass

print(res)
# (1, 1)
```